# Do the license plate numbers in Series of Unfortunate Events have any particular meaning?

Tags: unfortunate-events-2017

While watching episode 5 (Wide Window part 1), I noticed the licence plate on the taxi was 67-7-63.  Searching for this lead to [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ASOUE/comments/5ohy3t/no_spoilers_is_there_a_code_hidden_in_the_license/), which asks about them but is unanswered.

The plates listed are:

> 08-1-62 (Mr. Poe's car, from episode 3).
>   06-1-75 (Emily's car, from episode 3).
>   67-7-63 (Lake Lachrymose Taxi, from episode 5).
>   04-2-63 (Back of Lucky Smells Lumber Mill truck, from episode 6) 
>   26-0-13 (Hook handed man's car, from episode 6).
>   04-2-82 (Front of Lucky Smells Lumber Mill truck, from episode 7) .
>   06-1-75 (Buddy’s Refridgerator Repair, from episode 7)

Do these numbers have any meaning?

Comment: 677 was an address in book six, but this may be grasping at straws.

Comment: Most of them look like dates (e.g. Mr. Poe's Car would be either August 1, 1962 or January 8, 1962 depending on which country's convention you use). It may be worth cross-referencing with birthdays of cast and crew.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, none of the main cast or producers have birthdays matching these dates. I can only find the crew on IMDb, which don't have birthdays. Still, my money is on this since, excluding the ones starting in 67 and 26, it would refer to people aged 55, 42, 54 (x2), 35, and 42, which all sound like reasonable ages for people who would be working on the TV show.

Comment: After staring at this for a good minute or two, I've determined that "06-1-75" appears twice.  But... you probably already knew that.

Comment: @Kevin The list is copied from the link, but yes the number appears twice (although on 2 different vehicles).